# Facebook. Setting status using access token (offline access)

Tags: php, facebook

I am wondering how to set the status of a user who has allowed offline access permissions. I have the users ID and access token but can't figure out how to pass both to the function. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using facebook's PHP SDK?

Comment: Yes I am. I will be running from a cron job. The user has given the application permission to update their status (status changer app).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it in PHP SDK as `$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);`

Where `$access_token` is the token you want to set.

Also offline_access is deprecated.

Comment: so we need to save the access token first? And also, what is the validity of the access token?